# Does TestCafe support Test the App which build by NW.js? And how to do it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, testcafe, node-webkit

Well, my quention all write in the title. I had read TestCafe website and github, but never found some thing use TestCafe test with NW.js. Can someone tell me is support NW.js or not? If support, could give me a simple example? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have an desktop app build by NW.js and NW.js version is 0.61.0-sdk. I want to test it with testcafe, can testcafe success to test? If can, could give me a simple example about this?

Comment: There is currently no official support for NW.js. There are no appropriate modules in npm either ([https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=testcafe-browser-provider-](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=testcafe-browser-provider-)). You can try to implement such support yourself. To simplify the development of a plugin to support NW.js, use the [generator-testcafe-browser-provider module](https://github.com/DevExpress/generator-testcafe-browser-provider).